# Concatenate lines in a file

Tags: java, file-io

I have a number of data files which contain lines of contiguous character blocks, e.g.

```
thisisthefirstline
thisisthesecondline
thisisthethirdline
```

I am reading in each of these lines and concatenating them to create one long String which I then process. My question is, is there an elegant way to handle the concatenation of lines within a plaintext file?

Currently I am performing this task as follows:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sequence));
String line;
String sequence = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    sequence += line;
// do stuff with sequence here
```

Is there a way to achieve this using only the `sequence` container variable, and not the `line` temporary variable?

Comment: It is better to use StringBulder#append to concatenate Strings, less work for GC. Otherwise you code is ok and because of check for null value, it is not possible to simply remove line.

Comment: @JosefN Would you care to elaborate on how using a compound assignment affects garbage collection?

Comment: every time sequence += line; is executed a new object is created ad old string should be collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up using the following loop to perform the necessary String concatenation:

```
String seq = "";
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
    seq += line;
```

Although this does not avoid the use of a temporary variable, I think it is preferable to the standard `while-loop` approach. Here, the scope of the temporary variable `line` is limited to the loop where file processing actually occurs.

Answer (score 2):

No, each call to `BufferedReader#readLine()` reads until a new line is found or the stream ends. Therefore, you can't call it twice: once for `null` and once to assign it to some variable. You need to have an temporary placeholder for comparing and using its value.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with what you are currently doing.

Comment: You're right, there is nothing inherently wrong with it. I'd say it's the most common pattern for reading a file in Java. I was just wondering if there was a way to append lines to the container variable as part of the `null` check.

Comment: @voidHead Because you have to both check for `null` and append the value, you can't modify the code above to only use `line`. There are other ways to read the file however (as proposed by Maxim, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interesting quick way; use `readAllLines` (Java 7) and write:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("fileName"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String longString = Arrays.toString(lines.toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").replaceAll(", ","\t");
```

However, its not the best way to convert array to string.

I would use [Guava package](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html):

```
String longString = Joiner.on("\t").join(lines);
```

Comment: A very novel solution indeed, but the departure from a well-known pattern probably hurts readability.

Comment: agree, with 1st row we load file to array. And here you have list of options. The simple way to use loop and append to StringBuilder. The pretty clear way I think to use `join`

Comment: Good point, I suppose the way you handle parsing of the `List` is paramount. Using `readAllLines` is a good suggestion.